# -bash: /home/rb27/.bash_profile: Permission denied

Tags: linux, bashrc

I have tried changing permissions and I have looked for a solution, but the error still exists.In fact it gives me a different error every time I log in.

Could not chdir to home directory /home/rb27: Permission denied

here is a snippet of what I get when I use the command ls -al:

```
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root 0 Sep 8 18:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 4096 Feb 5 2011 ..
d????????? ? ? ? ? ? ajd74
d????????? ? ? ? ? ? ban45
d????????? ? ? ? ? ? rb27
```

I cannot log in as root since the permission is denied Please help

Comment: Will take note of that

Comment: Not enough information here. How is the filesystem mounted? What has changed since the last time you logged in? Is this your personal system, do you have root access?

Comment: I don't have root privileges. I use the ssh secure client and it was working fine. I don't know what happened then

Comment: You'll want to contact your systems administrator.

Comment: By the way, the people on Stack Overflow told you to ask here, but then they moved your question here. This lead to a double post, so in the future, please only post once and let the migration take care of it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

from your boot loader, give the following parameter to your Linux kernel:

```
init=/bin/sh
```

or

```
init=/bin/bash
```

Then go fix your permissions.  You'll probably need to run fsck too.

Comment: init: Need to be root.
 This is the output I get. The command i used is chmod 755 /home/rb27.Please tell me if I'm doing something wrong